# Triming the email portion of a username ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to retrieve the username of the current user through ASP.NET

Currently I am retrieving it with

```
string user = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

and I am trying to obtain the Student object that corresponds with the StudentNumber used to log into the Website.

> 10010800@bit.com |
> 10010822@bit.com

above are the users and I am trying to only have the long/int before the @bit.com.

After this, I am trying to query it against the database like this:

```
IQueryable<Student> student = db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentNumber == user);
```

but currently I am unable to do so since my conversion of the username isn't working.

```
user = Utility.StringModifier.Modifier(GetType().Name, "@bit.com");
```

Comment: `x.StudentNumber` what type is it in the DB?

Comment: @Rahatur it is of long type.

Comment: I have posted an answer

Comment: What is `Utility.StringModifier.Modifier`? Is that some custom code you've written? I ask because that seems to be the part of the question that you expect to actually extract the data you want, so including that implementation is critical to being able to find out how to change your code to do the proper thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string userName = Page.User.Identity.Name;
long studentNo = long.Parse(userName.Split('@')[0].Trim());
```

Then do your query:

```
IQueryable<Student> student = db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentNumber == studentNo );
```